# How to use Azure DevOps Analytics View to query data while creating SSIS package

Tags: ssis, azure-devops, odata, ssas

I'm looking to query against Azure DevOps analytical views through an SSIS package to ETL data to an on-prem SSAS. I've tried connecting with the OData source in VS2019 using SSIS, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: SO is a place for specific technical questions. You won't find much help with such a vague question

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you want to use OData to query Analytics for Azure DevOps in SSIS.

Your requirement could be split into two questions:

1. How to use OData to query Analytics for Azure DevOps?
2. How to use the OData Source in SSIS?

To exercise an OData query for Analytics in Azure DevOps, you must be granted the **View analytics** [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-security?view=azure-devops). To write OData queries against Analytics, check out the [OData Query Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/quick-ref?view=azure-devops). You could get start writing and testing OData queries from the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/odataquery-connect?view=azure-devops

Regarding how to use the OData Source in SSIS, you can refer to the following links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/tutorial-using-the-odata-source?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/odata-source?view=sql-server-ver15

You could check the documentations to get start or share more details if there is a specific query or error.